# Почему элементы массива не меняются?

Tags: c++, массивы

Задача: В массиве С(6,6) поменять местами элементы симметрично относительно 
главной диагонали. Почему у меня ничего не меняется местами?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    setlocale(0, "");
    int const n = 6;
    int i, k;

    int C[n][n]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
             C[i][j] = { rand() % 10 };
        }
    }
    cout << " Массив до изменений" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << C[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <n; j++){
            int temp = C[i][j];
            C[i][j] = C[j][i];
            C[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }

    cout << " Массив после изменений" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << C[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `C[i][j] = { rand() % 10 };` - это не ошибка, но это весьма странный синтаксис в данном контексте. Зачем вы поставили тут эти `{ ... }`?

Comment: Без них не работало

Comment: Не надо выдумывать. Без них все работает абсолютно точно так же, как и с ними. Никакой разницы нет.

Comment: Да работает, но когда я писал код почему-то Visual Studio выдавала ошибку.

Comment: Именно на *это* никакой ошибки Visual Studio не выдавало и выдавать не могло.

Comment: Ну я не знаю, возможно проблема была не конкретно в rand, но добавление  {} все решило, а почему и зачем уже не важно было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что элементы меняются местами дважды, и, таким образом, массив восстанавливает свое состояние

Чтобы избежать этого, нужно цикл обмена выполнять только для половины ячеек (и диагональ саму можно исключить)

```
  for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
```

Comment: Работает с измененной единственной строчкой, про которую я сказал: https://ideone.com/hDpZII